# Do cp and tar create temporary files and then do an atomic mv ?

Tags: centos, tar, java, cp, mv

I'm using Java's Files.walkFileTree to scan a particular directory periodically for *.csv files and then reading  them.

I know that mv is atomic ( at least within the same device ) so 'mv'ing a file shouldn't be a problem in terms of race condition.

If I do a cp instead, does cp first do a copy to a different filename, and then do a atomic mv to the original name ? Or will it cause a race condition by doing a direct read-write ?

I have the same question for extracting files to another directory using tar & gz .

PS. In case the answer is OS-dependent, I am working on CentOS 6. Also if possible can the answer be mentioned for Windows too ?

Comment: If you're concerned about reading a file that is still being written to, you could check the timestamp and ignore files less than X minutes old.  Or repeatedly check the file size every few seconds to see when it stops changing.   On linux, the best option would probably be to use `inotify` (there are java libraries for it) to tell you when a directory's contents change and when files in that directory are closed - i.e. wait for notification rather than periodic polling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GNU `cp` and GNU `tar` (the standard implementations on most Linux distros, including CentOS), they both create the file in-place.  I'm pretty sure the same is true of most other implementations as well.  It's not too hard to write a wrapper script to make it functionally atomic though.  I'm not sure about Windows, but I don't *think* that it provides any more guarantees that POSIX does for filesystem operation atomicity.

It's also worth noting also that `mv` is only atomic if it doesn't cross a filesystem boundary, otherwise it becomes equivalent to running `cp` and then unlinking the source file.